# Service is not running when app closed from backround. Issuse comes in Xiomi MI 5S+ and Samsung A7

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
/*Here i am setting alarm but it does not working in xiomi MI5S Plus when app removed from backround. */
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, START_DELAY);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnTrackerReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), /*UPDATE_INTERVAL*/
        Integer.parseInt(trackingInterval) * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);}
```

Method for set alarm, here tracking interval is in minute.

Comment: Give better format to your question please

Comment: @BrandonZamudio code  has been formatted so will you please suggest me any solution if you have.